# Navigation hover in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When I'm hover on second "li" I want to see some div.
I see this hidden div on bottom, but I want to see it on right side,
You can see on third screen what I want to do.

CSS:

```
#categories {
    display: none;
    left: 450px;
    top: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    clear: both;
}
.categories:hover #categories {
    display:block;

}
```

HTML:

```
<li class="categories">
<a href="#" class="menu"><img src="assets/img/icons/folders.svg" alt="" class="menu-icon"> მიმართულებები</a>
<div id="categories">some thing</div>
</li>
```

screen  1: before hover

[image: screen 1: before hover]

screen 2: on hover

[image: screen 2: after hover]

screen 3: what I want to see

[image: screen 3: what I want to see]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through below given css code , you can achieve the desired results

```
#categories {
display: none;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
background-color: red;
margin-left:26%;
margin-top:-4%;
}
.categories:hover #categories {
display:block;
}
```

link to its fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/6d0n80mt/11/